# Generating volume constrained splines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, spline

Suppose I have a set of 3 dimensional points, r_1,r_2, ...,r_n

suppose between points r_i and r_i+1 there is an associated volume V_i

I want to construct splines (i'm not fussy on what interpolation scheme could be used) between this set of points (in the order 1 to n), however each spline segment i (i.e. the spline between r_i and r_j) must remain in V_i.

Does Matlab offer this sort of functionality?

From what I gather spline generation has been thoroughly developed for Matlab, but I can't find the option to add in constraints. This make me think maybe this problem is not too trivial.

Comment: You question is not clear enough. your spline is a line, which you want to enclose in a "volume". How is the volume defined (square, spherical, polyhedral, tuboidal along the spline )... There is no built-in function that do random spline within constraints ... you will have to define your constraints explicitly, then randomize the degrees of freedom left.

Comment: I want to enclose the spline by the boundary of a volume. Specifically each V_i are tetrahedral elements, and the associated points with it lie on the centroids of two distinct faces of the tetrahedral.